# "Javascript" typo on documentation pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.2, documentation

On page *[Usage of /sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=default&run=true)*, it should be *[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)*, not *Javascript*, in the right sidebar:

[image]

This obviously also applies to (most/all) API documentation pages, since they share the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

This was just fixed in the latest build. Thanks for the report.